# How to prevent LaTeX from turning "a to an umlaut in German?

Tags: languages

I want to input a string `"a"` in a LaTeX document using German (`\documentclass[ngerman]{article}`), but I do not want `"a` to be turned into `ä`; what can I do? (I know `\verb` works; are there any other solutions?) Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

`\dq a` should work. Note also that proper quotation marks would be

```
"`like this"'
```

i.e. "quotation backtick" and "quotation apostrophe". (Also see the csquotes package.)

Answer (score 9):

Assuming that you really want the "straight" double quote: The correct command is `\textquotedbl` but `\string"` works too and is shorter:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\begin{document}
\string"a\string" 

\textquotedbl a\textquotedbl
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

other answers are appropriate if this is ordinary text.  but if you want, for example, to indicate how to type something, you may want to use "typewriter" style, so

```
\verb+"a"+
```

should give you a suitable result.

Answer (score 0):

1. Maybe it's a good thing if you improve your knowledge about quotation, but
2. for the moment simply write `"{}a{}"`

Comment: You assume that they want to quote something which is not stated in the question.

Comment: I'm coming to the party pretty late, but regarding point 1, it might have been nice to include a link to the documentation.